# RadioGroup fire OnCheckedChangeListener event on checked RadioButton

Tags: android, radio-group

in an android application I have a RadioGroup with multiple RadioButtons in it.

I implemented the `OnCheckedChangeListener` to capture checked change.

But this does not get fired it you click on a radio button that is already checked.

Is there a way to force the OnCheckedChangeListener to be called even if the user clicks on a radio button that is allready checked?

I thought of using `setOnClickListener` or `setOnTouchListener` but how can I get which radio button has been tapped if I use them? THey don't have a `checkedId` or index to know.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why do you need an event to trigger if it is already checked?

Comment: one of the radio button takes me to another page when checked. Then when you go back from that page I need it to stay checked, but if the user taps on it again I need to go to that page again even if checked. Note that that behavior is only for one of the radio buttons, the others do not take me to anohter page, that's why I need to know which one is being clicked

Comment: You shouldn't need to see if it's checked again...just if it's *still* checked. Before continuing, see if that `RadioButton` is checked

Comment: Actually you gave me an idea to put an onclicklistener on the radiobutton itself. That will only get fired when I click on that button. You can add it as an answer if you like and I will accept it. To add a click listener on each radio button separately.

Comment: I have posted an answer. Feel free to edit as you see fit to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, you can set an `OnClickListener` on each `RadioButton`. However, without knowing exactly what you are trying to accomplish, I don't see this as a viable solution. Users expect a `RadioButton` to act in a certain way. You may want to consider changing the checked state of the `RadioButton` each time the user returns to this `Activity`.

Comment: accepting this as it solves my problem. THe requirements were to have radio buttons but some of them need extra logic when clicked even if they are allready checked.